# Plot is empty (probably) due to poor function definition

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I am trying to plot my response $x(t)$ as a function of system parameter $M_0$. Here is my code to regenerate my problem

```
ω0 = Sqrt[kn/Jn];

β[j_] = 1/
  Sqrt[(1 - ((j 2 Pi)/(τ ω0))^2)^2 + (2 δ (
     j 2 Pi)/(τ ω0))^2];

ϕ[j_] = 
  ArcTan[(2 δ (j 2 Pi)/(τ ω0))/(
   1 - ((j 2 Pi )/(τ ω0))^2)];
 kn = 47000


ajj[j_, M0_] = -((
   M0 (-2 j Cos[(j π)/2]^2 - Sin[j π] + j^2 Sin[j π] + 
      3 Sin[2 j π] - 3 j^2 Sin[2 j π]))/(j (-1 + j^2) π));
bjj[j_, M0_] = (
  M0 (-2 + 2 j^2 - Cos[j π] + j^2 Cos[j π] + 
     3 Cos[2 j π] - 3 j^2 Cos[2 j π] + j Sin[j π]))/(
  j (-1 + j^2) π);

xAmp[t_, M0_, 
  num_] := (-2 M0 τ + 5 M0 π τ)/(π τ)/(2 kn) + 
  Sum[ajj[j, M0]/kn β[j] Cos[j 2 Pi t/τ - ϕ[j]], {j, 
    1, num}] + 
  Sum[bjj[j, M0]/kn β[j] Sin[j 2 Pi t/τ - ϕ[j]], {j, 
    1, num}]
```

Now `xAmp` should be a periodic function and my goal is to find out how the amplitude changes varying parameters `M0` and `kn`. Yet the definition above leaves my plot for fixed value of `M0`

```
Plot[xAmp[t, 270, 100], {t, 0, \[Tau]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

completely empty saying that an infinite expression 1/0 was encountered. I don't know where that infinite expression comes from because i calculated limits for all many many cases separately and none of them seemed problematic to me. So, how should I correct my `xAmp` definition in order to get at least something out and what is wrong with my definition?

Comment: Your `ajj` and `bjj` functions have a `(j (-1 + j^2) π)` in the denominator, which is zero when you sum from `j=1`

Comment: @JasonB yes, but limits: `Limit[ajj[j,210],j->1]` and  `Limit[bjj[j,210],j->1]` are both finite and real.

Comment: aha, but you didn't ask for the `Limit` did you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ajj` and `bjj` functions have a `(j (-1 + j^2) π)` in the denominator, which is zero when you sum from `j=1`.  Consider this term,

```
x = ajj[j, 40]
(* -((40 (-2 j Cos[(j π)/2]^2 - Sin[j π] + j^2 Sin[j π] + 
    3 Sin[2 j π] - 3 j^2 Sin[2 j π]))/(j (-1 + j^2) π)) *)
```

Now if you simply substitute 1 for `j` in the above, the system will see that zero in the denominator and complain.

```
x /. j -> 1

During evaluation of Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

During evaluation of Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression (0 ComplexInfinity)/π encountered. >>
(* Indeterminate *)
```

But if you take the [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) instead,

```
Limit[x, j -> 1]
(* 0 *)
```

there is no problem.  So redefine your functions,

```
ajj[j_, M0_] := 
  Limit[-((M0 (-2 jj Cos[(jj π)/2]^2 - Sin[jj π] + 
          j^2 Sin[jj π] + 3 Sin[2 jj π] - 
          3 jj^2 Sin[2 jj π]))/(jj (-1 + jj^2) π)), jj -> j];
bjj[j_, M0_] := 
  Limit[(M0 (-2 + 2 jj^2 - Cos[jj π] + jj^2 Cos[jj π] + 
        3 Cos[2 jj π] - 3 jj^2 Cos[2 jj π] + 
        jj Sin[jj π]))/(jj (-1 + jj^2) π), jj -> j];
```

and you can now evaluate the functions just fine,

```
ajj[1, 40]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Ok that explains my questions. Tthank you. I was thinking about using Limits but I got completely confused when limits ajj[j] anf bjj[j] were both finite and real.

Comment: Glad to help, but be careful in using the `Limit` function, since it doesn't fully localize the variable.  I had first tried it with `ajj[jj_, M0_]:= Limit[......., j->jj]` and it ran into trouble since the summation variable is also `j`.